# Combining Flux entry with previous and map

Tags: java, project-reactor

## Question

With a Flux how do you access previous element?

### Background

I have an external event stream, that gives events in order, the order of that stream is to dispatch one event and immediately afterwards to dispatch another event. However the metadata for the second event is in the first event.

Note that it isn't always an even number of events.

What I'm trying to do is combine the events into a stream of events for consumption downstream.

`Flux#zip` looked promising but it would mean returning an object of the external event type.

### Inital code

So far what I've got is.

```
    BinaryLogClient client = new BinaryLogClient(host, port, username, password);
    Flux<Event> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
        EventListener fluxListener = event -> {
            sink.next(event);
        };

        client.registerEventListener(fluxListener);
    });

    bridge.subscribe(DemoApplication::printEvent);
    bridge.map(new EventPairMemorizer());


public class EventPair  {
    private final Event previous;
    private final Event current;

    public EventPair(Event previous, Event current) {
        this.previous = previous;
        this.current = current;
    }

    /**
     * @return `null` if no previous events.
     */
    public Event getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public Event getCurrent() {
        return current;
    }
}

/**
 * Not thread safe has to go on a single thread
 */
public class EventPairMemorizer implements Function<Event, EventPair> {
    Event previous = null;

    EventPair toPair(Event e) {
        EventPair pair = new EventPair(previous, e);
        previous = e;
        return pair;
    }

    @Override
    public EventPair apply(Event current) {
        return toPair(current);
    }
}
```

This is partly a learning exercise, partially a proof of concept.

### Irrelevant Details

I'm attempting to use mysql-binlog-connector-java to get a stream on whats changed in the database.

So If I receive a `EXT_WRITE_ROWS` event the previous event is a `TABLE_MAP` event. I then want to do a column lookup on the `TABLE_MAP` event (using jdbc). Then convert to some internal structure that is JSON friendly.

The same applies for a `EXT_UPDATE_ROWS` event.

So the idea code looks like

1. onExternalEvent push to Flux
2. check event type. If matching call jdbc on jdbc thread using Mono
3. combine Mono and current event.
4. map to internal type.
5. emit to a different stream.
6. profit

Comment: note reactive programming is not necessarily the best fit when one needs to access past elements in the sequence: although there are ways to achieve that they can be more roundabout than imperative solutions for simple problems

Comment: @SimonBaslé agreed however it is partly a learning exercise.  I've done some coding in the past with vert.x but this is different and I'm trying to learn how its done. Also the idea of effectively connecting to an event stream, transforming and supplying another event stream seemed to me to be the purpose of Ractor but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

How about overlapping buffers?

With `buffer(2, 1)` you would open a buffer for every element, and each buffer would contain 2 elements.

You can then ignore the buffers that don't **end** with an event you're interested in, and get the previous value for the events you ARE interested in...

Comment: This seems reasonable and does appear to work.  I do dislike the interface of a Flux<List<Event>> as it appears more generic than actually is acceptable. However it also appers to be a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.scan()`

```
Flux<EventPair> pairs = bridge.scan(new EventPair(null,null),(prevPair,newEvent)->
  new EventPair(prevPair.current,newEvent)
);
```